# Prove {$I$ , $A$ , $A^2$ ,...., $A^{n-1}$} is a basis for W

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $F$ be a field , $A$ $\in$  $M_{n\times n} $($F$) (the set of all $n\times n$ matrices over field $F$ ) and $W$ = { $ B \in M_{n\times n } (F)$ $|$ $AB = BA$ }.  Suppose there exists a column vector $v \in F^n$ such that { $v$ , $Av$ , $A^2 v$ , ... , $A^{n - 1} v$ } is a basis for $F^n$

a) Prove that  $I$ , $A$ , $A^2$ ,...., $A^{n-1}$ are linearly independent vectors contained in $W$

b) Prove that  {$I$ , $A$ , $A^2$ ,...., $A^{n-1}$} is a basis of W

I used proof by contradiction to solve part a. But I'm stuck at part b.

I know W  is a subspace of $M_{n×n}(F)$. Also, since we already know the set {$I$ , $A$ , $A^2$ ,...., $A^{n-1}$}
is linearly independent. I need to show that {$I$ , $A$ , $A^2$ ,...., $A^{n-1}$} spans W to prove that it is a basis.
Its easy to prove that  if $x \in$ span{$I$ , $A$ , $A^2$ ,...., $A^{n-1}$} then $x \in W$. But I am unable to prove the converse to complete the proof.

I have tried the following approach. Let $B \in W$

One can create the columns of B and solve the problem. Since { $v$ , $Av$ , $A^2 v$ , ... , $A^{n - 1} v$ } is a basis for $F^n$ , We know there exists linear combinations such that

$a_0v + a_1 A v + a_2 A^2 v + ... +a_{n-1} A^{n-1}v$ = $B e_1$ - (1st column of B)

$b_0v + b_1 A v + b_2 A^2 v + ... +b_{n-1} A^{n-1}v$ = $B e_2$ - (2nd column of B)

$c_0v + c_1 A v + c_2 A^2 v + ... +c_{n-1} A^{n-1}v$ = $B e_3$ - (3rd column of B)

so on... till n columns

where $e_i$ represents the $i$th the column of the identity Matrix

I am trying to create matrix B by [$Be_1$  $Be_2$ ... $Be_n$] and solve the problem. But I can't seem to be able to bring {$I$ , $A$ , $A^2$ ,...., $A^{n-1}$} out. 
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Alright got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 
\begin{equation*}\tag{basis}
v,  Av,  A^2 v, \dots , A^{n - 1} v
\end{equation*}
is a basis for $F^{n}$,  any matrix is determined by its action on (basis).

Now let $B \in W$. Since $B$ commutes with $A$, we have $$B (A^{i} v) = A^{i} (B v),$$ that is, **the action of $B$ on the whole (basis) is determined by its action on $v$ alone**. The same clearly holds for any linear combination $C$ of powers of $A$, as such $C$ commute with $A$, and thus also lie in $W$.

So if
\begin{equation*}
B v = c_{0} v + c_{1} A v + \dots + c_{n-1} A^{n-1} v
= (c_{0} I + c_{1} A  + \dots + c_{n-1} A^{n-1}) v,
\end{equation*}
we have then
\begin{equation*}\tag{equality}
B = c_{0} I + c_{1} A  + \dots + c_{n-1} A^{n-1},
\end{equation*}
as LHS and RHS of (equality) agree on $v$, and both sides commute with $A$, so their action on $v$ alone determines them completely.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you so much! Essentially we can bring v out out therefore its equal. Just to clarify. I was initially hesitant to cancel vectors and matrices. So for example consider Matrices A,B,C,D ,E,K. Let ABCDE =KE . Then in general it is not true that ABCD = K . But if A,B,C,D all commute with each other, any action on A or B or C or D completely determines the action/effect on E. Therefore we can say ABCD = K. Am I correct?

Comment: @Sundeep, no, rather, the point is that the underlying vector space $V = F^{n}$ becomes a cyclic $F[A]$-module, generated by $v$. The elements of $W$ are the endomorphism of $V$ as a $F[A]$-module.